# Akka stream hangs when starting more than 15 external processes using ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, processbuilder

I'm building an app that has the following flow:

1. There is a source of items to process
2. Each item should be processed by external command (it'll be `ffmpeg` in the end but for this simple reproducible use case it is just `cat` to have data be passed through it)
3. In the end, the output of such external command is saved somewhere (again, for the sake of this example it just saves it to a local text file)

So I'm doing the following operations:

1. Prepare a source with items
2. Make an Akka graph that uses Broadcast to fan-out the source items into individual flows
3. Individual flows uses `ProcessBuilder` in conjunction with `Flow.fromSinkAndSource` to build flow out of this external process execution
4. End the individual flows with a sink that saves the data to a file.

Complete code example:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.ClosedShape
import akka.util.ByteString

import java.io.{BufferedInputStream, BufferedOutputStream}
import java.nio.file.Paths
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

object MyApp extends App {

  // When this is changed to something above 15, the graph just stops
  val PROCESSES_COUNT = Integer.parseInt(args(0))

  println(s"Running with ${PROCESSES_COUNT} processes...")

  implicit val system                          = ActorSystem("MyApp")
  implicit val globalContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global

  def executeCmdOnStream(cmd: String): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, _] = {
    val convertProcess = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start
    val pipeIn         = new BufferedOutputStream(convertProcess.getOutputStream)
    val pipeOut        = new BufferedInputStream(convertProcess.getInputStream)
    Flow
      .fromSinkAndSource(StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() ⇒ pipeIn), StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() ⇒ pipeOut))
  }

  val source = Source(1 to 100)
    .map(element => {
      println(s"--emit: ${element}")
      ByteString(element)
    })

  val sinksList = (1 to PROCESSES_COUNT).map(i => {
    Flow[ByteString]
      .via(executeCmdOnStream("cat"))
      .toMat(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(s"process-$i.txt")))(Keep.right)
  })

  val graph = GraphDSL.create(sinksList) { implicit builder => sinks =>

    val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[ByteString](sinks.size))
    source ~> broadcast.in
    for (i <- broadcast.outlets.indices) {
      broadcast.out(i) ~> sinks(i)
    }
    ClosedShape
  }

  Await.result(Future.sequence(RunnableGraph.fromGraph(graph).run()), Duration.Inf)

}
```

Run this using following command:

```
sbt "run PROCESSES_COUNT"
```

i.e.

```
sbt "run 15"
```

This all works quite well until I raise the amount of "external processes" (PROCESSES_COUNT in the code). When it's **15** or less, all goes well but when it's **16 or more** then the following things happen:

1. Whole execution just hangs after emitting the first 16 items (this amount of 16 items is Akka's default buffer size AFAIK)
2. I can see that `cat` processes are started in the system (**all 16 of them**)
3. When I manually kill one of these `cat` processes in the system, something frees up and processing continues (of course in the result, one file is empty because I killed its processing command)

I checked that this is caused by the external execution for sure (not i.e. limit of Akka Broadcast itself).

I [recorded a video](https://github.com/aszmyd/akka-streams-process-limits/blob/main/akka-processes.mp4?raw=true) showing these two situations (first, 15 items working fine and then 16 items hanging and freed up by killing one process) - link to the video

Both the code and video are in [this repo](https://github.com/aszmyd/akka-streams-process-limits)

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions where to look solution for this one.

Comment: Hmm, I like akka-streams but I am wondering if it is the right tool for the job vs using  ffmpeg from the shell, see https://superuser.com/questions/538164/how-many-instances-of-ffmpeg-commands-can-i-run-in-parallel

Comment: I actually need to avoid any filesystem operations, that's why I decided to do it in streams. I don't have any source input file to process but just a stream of mixed data that I process and generate various assets out of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an interesting problem and it looks like that the stream is dead-locking. The increase of threads may be fixing the symptom but not the underlying problem.

The problem is following code

```
Flow
  .fromSinkAndSource(
    StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() => pipeIn),
    StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => pipeOut)
  )
```

Both `fromInputStream` and `fromOutputStream` will be using the same `default-blocking-io-dispatcher` as you correctly noticed. The reason for using a dedicated thread pool is that both perform Java API calls that are blocking the running thread.

Here is a part of a thread stack trace of `fromInputStream` that shows where blocking is happening.

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(java.base@11.0.13/Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.13/FileInputStream.java:279)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(java.base@11.0.13/BufferedInputStream.java:290)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.13/BufferedInputStream.java:351)
- locked <merged>(a java.lang.ProcessImpl$ProcessPipeInputStream)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(java.base@11.0.13/BufferedInputStream.java:290)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.13/BufferedInputStream.java:351)
- locked <merged>(a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.13/FilterInputStream.java:107)
at akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamSource$$anon$1.onPull(InputStreamSource.scala:63)
```

Now, you're running `16` simultaneous `Sink`s that are connected to a single `Source`. To support back-pressure, a `Source` will only produce an element when **all** `Sink`s send a `pull` command.

What happens next is that you have 16 calls to method `FileInputStream.readBytes` at the same time and they immediately block all threads of `default-blocking-io-dispatcher`. And there are no threads left for `fromOutputStream` to write any data from the `Source` or perform any kind of work. Thus, you have a dead-lock.

The problem can be fixed if you increase the threads in the pool. But this just removes the symptom.

The correct solution is to run `fromOutputStream` and `fromInputStream` in two separate thread pools. Here is how you can do it.

```scala
Flow
  .fromSinkAndSource(
    StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() => pipeIn).async("blocking-1"),
    StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => pipeOut).async("blocking-2")
  )
```

with following config

```
blocking-1 {
  type = "Dispatcher"
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 2
  }
}

blocking-2 {
  type = "Dispatcher"
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 2
  }
}
```

Because they don't share the pools anymore, both `fromOutputStream` and `fromInputStream` can perform their tasks independently.

Also note that I just assigned `2` threads per pool to show that it's not about the thread count but about the pool separation.

I hope this helps to understand akka streams better.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It indeed is fixing the problem. But I wonder - what are potential issues with just increasing the default thread pool vs making separate dispatchers? I'm asking because in my real application at first the solution with dispatchers didn't work and I realize I have one more place where IO operations are being made which needed its own, third dispatcher. I'm just curios what could go wrong with this default thread increase (assuming I know I won't ever reach the value I'll set it to)

Comment: @AdamSzmyd the worst case that it will dead-lock in production if you have some dynamic behavior that would increase the amount of sinks you have. I think it's a good idea to have a separate dispatcher for every blocking stage/flow/sink/source in one single runable graph.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was limit on [Akka configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration-reference.html) level of blocking IO dispatchers:

[image]

So changing that value to something bigger than the amount of streams fixed the issue:

```
akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher.thread-pool-executor.fixed-pool-size = 50
```

Comment: this just fixes the symptoms. Check my answer for more details